# Reading from a TCP socket when deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, sockets, heroku, apple-push-notifications

We have python application that communicates with Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) for

1. sending push notifications
2. gathering information about devices unreachable to push notifications (Feedback Service)

Both cases require opening a socket connection to APNS and

1. sending a package that contains one or more notifications as a payload
2. querying the socket for ids of unreachable devices.

While sending works smoothly, it seems that we are unable to *receive* anything from the opened socket. Has anybody encountered a similar problem with Heroku? On local environment everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Heroku doesn't allow other than HTTP traffic to be handled by your application. It is a common restriction for PaaS services.

There is an addon, however, called [Ruppell's Sockets](https://addons.heroku.com/ruppells-sockets) that allows you to receive TCP traffic. Basically what it does is just listens for TCP connections on its own socket and then forwards the data to your application. It is currently in Beta, and **I want to warn you that I currently have serious issues with it on my project**. The outgoing traffic often doesn't get to a client. So, if possible, deploy somewhere else where you can assure more clear TCP environment.